# Chain pre-launch tasks in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

Is it possible to invoke more than one pre-launch task using VS Code?

I try to restore packages then build then run but I can only get to configure build.

My launch.json:

```
{
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/myProject/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/myProject.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src/myProject",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "externalConsole": false
    },
```

My tasks.json:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "dotnet",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": [],
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "args": [
            "./**/project.json"
            ],
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always",
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
```

}

so I tried to specify the `dotnet restore` command however it does not work.

Comment: How are you configuring the tasks?

Comment: I hace The prelaunchtask:"build" as the default that gets generated when you get the prompt for creating your launch.json. However I don't know if that argument could accept more than one task or whether you can define dependencies in your tasks.json so that I could run restore prior build. Does that make sense? I have also tried to do that in the args of the task: "dotnet restore && dotnet build" but I can't get it to work

Comment: Could you post your `project.json` and any other relevant configuration files?

Comment: I edited my question by adding the launch.json and tasks.json

Comment: did you ever find answer to this question? I want to know as well.

Comment: I didn’t. I started using VS again for .NET Core as it worked like a charm. I wanted to switch to a lighter IDE for this but I think this was the beginning and wasn’t very well supported. I guess now is a different story and should work nicely

Answer (score 0):

I know this is long over due. However, I think I figured out the solution. Steps  I did.

1. Create a workspace to include all the projects in the workspace.
2. Go to Run and Debug, and click on "Add Config (workspace)
3. the format is the following:

   {
   "folders": [
   {
   "path": "project1"
   },
   {
   "path": "project2"
   },
   ],
   "launch": {
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "compounds": [{
   "name": "Chain Stars",
   "configurations": [
   "ConfigurationName1",
   "ConfigurationName2",
   ]
   }]
   }
   }

ConfigurationName1, and ConfigurationName2 is the profile name you would like to put them in sequence to launch your website.
4. Save the profile. In this case. "Chain Stars" is going to show up in the profile name for you to run it. Let me know if you have any questions.